# How can I get a Directory Listing of Files i gave my Android App with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, file-io

I want to add x Files to a folder resources in Eclipse

Now I want to get a List with the unknown number and names of Files in the specified Folder like:

```
File directory = new File("resources/");

String[] dirArray = directory.list();
```

Where do I put the Files in Eclipse and where are they once my app is started?
I can get the directory Info for / but that's about it.

Thanks in advance!
 Taber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can add resources to an app after you create it.  You need to store them using other methods.  For example using externalStorage, or the hidden storage available where the app was installed.

Edit:  The Data storage developer doc is located [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).  It gives you a great explanation of how you might go about storing your data.  Since you are using images, some methods won't be appropriate for you.

Comment: And where is this internal storage and how can I add files with eclipse to it?

Comment: You should read the Data Storage Developer doc.  Post updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Android File Browser example [here](http://www.anddev.org/android_filebrowser__v20-t101.html)? I dont think you can add resources, but you can create a different folder to save files to. Read this example and tweak it for your needs.

The files you put in the folders in Eclipse projects are given memory addresses to be placed in and referenced from at runtime, therefore you cant add resources to an app after you create it.

Comment: How can I get the Folder resources I added to my Eclipse Project at runtime? File resources = ???

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add files to the Android emulator or the actual application? If you want to put files into the emulator, just go into the DDMS perspective. Then you can browse your device's directories and push files into it.

Comment: I already added files to data/local/tmp/ via DDMS and tried to access them via: File dir = new File("/data/local/tmp/");    String[] filesArray = dir.list();  but the filesArray is Null. I don't know how the adressing scheme seems to be working or if i'm missing permissions etc. for "/" is's working.